# mysql error connecting to the server did not ask for password during the installation process

Tags: mysql

I wanted to learn MySQL, so I decided to download it from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/. However, during the installation it did not ask me for any password, now I cannot connect to the server as it needs a password. I have tried reinstalling it but it still does not ask for the password. Can somebody tell what the problem is?

Comment: MySQL installs with the default user 'root' and has no password. You can set up or change the users with additional queries, once logged in

Comment: then i dont understand why am i not able to connect to the server

Comment: Have you tried connecting with root?

Comment: This link describes the initial account and how to secure it - it may be of some use: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: which version you install,  MySQL create root user by default with temporary password which you'll find in error/log file.

Comment: you have a mysql bronze badge and a JDBC gold badge

Answer (score 2):

It happens to me several times, if you want to solve this download the full package installer. The second installer from the link you posted. I think that will save you from unnecessary headache.

I hope I’m able to help?

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and run the below cmd after this one gets into the MySQL server.

```
sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

To change the password of any user you can use the below query

```
ALTER USER '{USER_NAME}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '{YOUR NEW PASSWORD}';
```